# Heapify each sublist in a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, heap

I have a list of lists called opened which was declared like this:

```
opened = [[] for i in range(5)]
```

Now `opened = [[], [], [], [], []]`
How can I heapify each of the sublists using the `heapq.heapify()` function? i.e, opened[0], opened[1], opened[2], opened[3], opened[4] should be heapified.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of those sub-lists is a list, so just use `heapify()` directly on each of them:

```
import heapq

for j in range(5):
    heapq.heapify(opened[j])
```

Of course, if you know that each of those sub-lists is empty, there is no need to do this: an empty list is already a heap. There are no extra variables or other storage to make them heaps, since a Python heap is just a list with a condition on the order of the elements.